# Wildfly 21 with eclipselink 3.0 getting error as Persistence Provider not found

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb, wildfly, eclipselink

Wildfly Version: 21.0.2.Final

JDK Version: openjdk-11.0.2

Eclipselink: Migrating from 2.7.8 to 3.0.0 ( **2.7.8 working fine**)

When I try to deploy EJB 3.2 (JPA 2.2) project I am getting the below issue

```
10:29:59,261 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."AAA-EAR.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."AAA-EAR.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "AAA-EAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1001)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.nextPhaseDependsOnPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1044)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
```

Eclipselink 2.7.8 working fine, so I just updated eclipselink version to 3.0 in below module.xml.
Also I think no need to exclude javax as this folder does not in eclipselink 3.0 jar.

wildfly-21.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main/module.xml

```
<module name="org.eclipse.persistence" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="public"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-21.0.2.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="eclipselink-3.0.0.jar">
          <filter>
             <exclude path="javax/**" />
          </filter>
       </resource-root>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Below is my META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AAA-EJB"  transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>**org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider**</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/Test</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.refresh" value="true"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
    </properties> 
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Eclipselink 2.7.8 working fine but getting issue for Eclipselink 3.0.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: Thanks for this hint! I almost gave up. I will downgrade for now.

Comment: @Eric  No. Im using older Eclipselink.

Comment: Are you aware that _"The primary focus of the EclipseLink 3.0 release is switch over to new 'jakarta' package namespace and support for Jakarta EE 9 APIs."_ https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/3.0.php